# Belgian Frites - French Fries

Tags: frying, potatoes, deep-frying, french-fries

In Belgium fries are super popular. They taste really amazing and are very different than the common American french fry. My question is, what is the secret to replicate a Belgian style french fry. They have a perfectly crispy golden shell, about 1inch wide, 1/3 inch thick, soft on the inside and totally different than your average American style french fry.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, frites are double fried. You wash, peel, and cut the potatoes (thicker, as you noted)*, then fry the potatoes at a lower temperature (325F is what I usually do). Then you let them drip the excess oil off on a wire rack or stack of paper towels, toss to coat them in cornstarch and fry again in hotter oil (400F). They're also usually fried in smaller batches in shallower oil than tradition shoestring fires. 
The really cool thing with them is that you can freeze them between the two fry times, so you can basically have your own frozen fries ready to go at any time.

*Drop the cut potatoes in water to prevent discoloration and then dry them a bit before frying if you're cutting a lot.

Comment: The cornstarch coating sounds like an interesting detail - not commonly found in recipes. Wonder how common this practice is?

Comment: That's how we always did it in a restaurant I used to work in. I recently got a cookbook with international potato recipes that also mentions this method, attributing it to Europe. So I guess its fairly common? Maybe?